# Has a civil aviation accident ever involved more than two manned aircraft?

Tags: accidents

Has a civil aviation accident ever involved more than two manned aircraft? Meaning, in one accident: more than two manned aircraft had fatalities or serious injuries or significant damage; or one or two manned aircraft had fatalities or serious injuries or significant damage, while other manned aircraft contributed to the accident, totaling three or more aircraft.

If military aircraft were involved, that would also be of interest, as long as at least one aircraft was civil aviation.

Comment: This would only happen when one hits the other two on the ground.

Answer (score 4):

The [Ramstein Airshow Disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramstein_air_show_disaster) comes to mind, where one airplane of the Italian Air Force display team collided with 2 others during a display, so 3 airplanes were involved in the collision in the air. A medivac helicopter on the ground was also destroyed, which was manned at the time, fatally injuring the pilot.

Comment: This is very good info. But is it considered civil aviation?

Comment: No, but there were many civilian deaths,  and the question said if military aircraft were involved it would be of interest.

Answer (score -2):

I found a case of an aircraft crashing into a hangar, damaging two more aircraft, bringing the total to three.

> The Federal Aviation Administration said the plane had just taken off for St. Petersburg, Florida, when it crashed into the private hangar. There was no one inside the hangar at the time of the crash, but two aircraft, a helicopter and a jet were damaged, Landsberg said.

[Source](https://www.nbcdfw.com/news/local/small-plane-crashes-into-hangar-at-addison-airport/212810/)

Surely there have been similar accidents with more material damage.

Comment: If nobody was inside the hangar, how can the two aircraft damaged inside it be manned?